# Unable to deserialize a com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job object

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

```
   public void serializeJob(Job job) throws IOException {
    // Using Json
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type type = new TypeToken<Job>() {}.getType();
    String jobJson = gson.toJson(job, type);
    System.out.println(jobJson);

    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("job.txt")) {
        out.println(jobJson);
    }

    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("job.txt")));
    Job job1 = gson.fromJson(content, type);
    // Using Jackson
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();        
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    String jacksonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(job);
    mapper.readValue(jacksonString, Job.class);

}
```

I am trying to Persist the **com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job** object in a file,  want to deserialise it, and use that in my junit test. Now the problem here is when i am trying to serialise using gson , it is getting serialized and storing in a file. But When i am trying to deserialize it , it is throwing the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke public com.google.api.gax.retrying.RetrySettings() with no args
at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:113)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:963)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:928)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:877)
at JobMetrics.serializeJob(JobMetrics.java:98)
at ProjectDetails.main(ProjectDetails.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:110)
```

I also tried removing the unnecessary fields in the file which are causing exception, finally i encountered another exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobId() with no args
at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:113)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:212)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:131)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:222)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:963)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:928)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:877)
at JobMetrics.serializeJob(JobMetrics.java:98)
at ProjectDetails.main(ProjectDetails.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException
at sun.reflect.InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(InstantiationExceptionConstructorAccessorImpl.java:48)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$3.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java:110)
... 8 more
```

I also tried using jackson , but serialization itself is not happening in jackson. Can anyone suggest a way which helps in serializing and deserializing my job object .

Thanks

Comment: Could you share a code snippet?

Comment: The above one is code Snippet, i didn't get you what exactly the details you required ?